# Need suggestion on embedding website into mobile app with authentication

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I need your suggestion on this particular problem.
I am trying to embed a web-app into flutter mobile using WebView or just say an mobile app in general. That web-app does has the authentication, only users have correct username/password can login.

However, The mobile has the authentication part as well. I dont want users to login 2 times, mobile app then web app, but in the mean time, I dont want users access web-app or mobile app without logging in.

I would like user login to the mobile app and somehow authenticate to access to the web-app as well. I am trying to make this connection secure.

Solution that i am thinking now is that: getting username and password from mobile app. Then pass it to the url of that web-app. and then the Web-app will do the rest.

Any suggestion ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Do NOT put the password into the URL.  That has severe security issues-  anyone within your company who has access to your http logs will be able to see your user's passwords.

If the web app is being brought up as part of the mobile app it should be easy.  When you authenticate, you sent some token down to recognize future requests.  Send that token as a header or cookie when you go to the website, and have the web app look for that header and authenticate with that token.  Your web app is already doing that via cookies, so if you send the token as a cookie and your web and api servers use the same authentication tokens, you're good.

If the web app is being brought up in an external browser, then you're pretty much out of luck and they'll have to log in twice.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am just using the WebView to display the web, a part of flutter ( i assume its an internal tool). Let me try your suggestion. Thanks again. Thats were helpful.